# Export a list of tables separately using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract all tables from a text file like https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1961/0001264931-18-000031.txt. I want to iterate over each table and if it contains a certain string (income tax), I want to export it using pandas dataframes. However, I keep getting the error that I cannot export a list. I know I am overlooking something simple, but how does my code not export every table separately

```py
for filename, text in tqdm(dìctionary.items()):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "lxml")
    tables = soup.find_all('table')
    for i, table in enumerate(tables):
        if ('income tax' in str(table)) or ('Income tax' in str(table)):
            df = pd.read_html(str(table))
            nametxt = filename.strip('.txt')
            name = nametxt.replace("/", "") 
            df.to_csv('mypath\\' + name + '_%s.csv' %i)
        else:
            pass
```

```py
0% 0/6547 [00:00<?, ?it/s]



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-99-e7794eac8da6> in <module>()
      7             nametxt = filename.strip('.txt')
      8             name = nametxt.replace("/", "")
----> 9             df.to_csv('mypath\\' + name + '_%s.csv' %i)
     10         else:
     11             pass

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

df looks like this:

```py
[                                                    0   1         2  \
0                                         Worlds Inc. NaN       NaN   
1                            Statements of Cash Flows NaN       NaN   
2               Year Ended December 31, 2017 and 2016 NaN       NaN   
3                                                 NaN NaN   Audited   
4                                                 NaN NaN  12/31/17   
5               Cash flows from operating activities: NaN       NaN   
6                                     Net gain/(loss) NaN         $   
7   Adjustments to reconcile net loss to net cash ... NaN       NaN   
8             Loss on settlement of convertible notes NaN       NaN   
9                  Fair value of stock options issued NaN       NaN   
10                      Fair value of warrants issued NaN       NaN   
11           Amortization of discount to note payable NaN       NaN   
12    Changes in fair value of derivative liabilities NaN       NaN   
13              Accounts payable and accrued expenses NaN       NaN   
14                          Due from/to related party NaN       NaN   
15           Net cash (used in) operating activities: NaN       NaN   
16                                                NaN NaN       NaN   
17                                                NaN NaN       NaN   
18               Cash flows from financing activities NaN       NaN   
19             Proceeds from issuance of note payable NaN       NaN   
20  Proceeds from issuance of convertible note pay... NaN       NaN   
21   Cash paid to repurchase convertible note payable NaN       NaN   
22             Proceeds from issuance of common stock NaN       NaN   
23                 Proceeds from exercise of warrants NaN       NaN   
24  Issuance of common stock as payment for accoun... NaN       NaN   
25          Net cash provided by financing activities NaN       NaN   
26                                                NaN NaN       NaN   
27  Net increase/(decrease) in cash and cash equiv... NaN       NaN   
28                                                NaN NaN       NaN   
29  Cash and cash equivalents, including restricte... NaN       NaN   
30                                                NaN NaN       NaN   
31  Cash and cash equivalents, including restricte... NaN         $   
32                                                NaN NaN       NaN   
33                      Non-cash financing activities NaN       NaN   
34  Issuance of 54,963,098 shares of common stock ... NaN       NaN   
35                                                NaN NaN       NaN   
36  Supplemental disclosure of cash flow information: NaN       NaN   
37                     Cash paid during the year for: NaN       NaN   
38                                           Interest NaN         $   
39                                       Income taxes NaN         $   
40                                                NaN NaN       NaN   
41  The accompanying notes are an integral part of... NaN       NaN   

             3         4   5    6           7    8  
0          NaN       NaN NaN  NaN         NaN  NaN  
1          NaN       NaN NaN  NaN         NaN  NaN  
2          NaN       NaN NaN  NaN         NaN  NaN  
3          NaN   Audited NaN  NaN         NaN  NaN  
4          NaN  12/31/16 NaN  NaN         NaN  NaN  
5          NaN       NaN NaN  NaN         NaN  NaN  
6   (2,746,968         ) NaN    $  (1,132,906    )  
7          NaN       NaN NaN  NaN         NaN  NaN  
8          NaN       NaN NaN  NaN      246413  NaN  
9      1041264       NaN NaN  NaN           —  NaN  
10     1215240       NaN NaN  NaN           —  NaN  
11           —       NaN NaN  NaN        5000  NaN  
12           —       NaN NaN  NaN      (6,191    )  
13      267983       NaN NaN  NaN      237577  NaN  
14     (21,051         ) NaN  NaN     (31,257    )  
15    (243,532         ) NaN  NaN    (681,364    )  
16         NaN       NaN NaN  NaN         NaN  NaN  
17         NaN       NaN NaN  NaN         NaN  NaN  
18         NaN       NaN NaN  NaN         NaN  NaN  
19           —       NaN NaN  NaN      290000  NaN  
20           —       NaN NaN  NaN      156500  NaN  
21         NaN       NaN NaN  NaN    (175,257    )  
22         NaN       NaN NaN  NaN      350000  NaN  
23      292800       NaN NaN  NaN      127200  NaN  
24       25582       NaN NaN  NaN           —  NaN  
25      318382       NaN NaN  NaN      748443  NaN  
26         NaN       NaN NaN  NaN         NaN  NaN  
27       74849       NaN NaN  NaN       67079  NaN  
28         NaN       NaN NaN  NaN         NaN  NaN  
29       93378       NaN NaN  NaN       26298  NaN  
30         NaN       NaN NaN  NaN         NaN  NaN  
31      168229       NaN NaN    $       93379  NaN  
32         NaN       NaN NaN  NaN         NaN  NaN  
33         NaN       NaN NaN  NaN         NaN  NaN  
34           —       NaN NaN  NaN      384159  NaN  
35         NaN       NaN NaN  NaN         NaN  NaN  
36         NaN       NaN NaN  NaN         NaN  NaN  
37         NaN       NaN NaN  NaN         NaN  NaN  
38           —       NaN NaN    $     (34,916    )  
39           —       NaN NaN    $           —  NaN  
40         NaN       NaN NaN  NaN         NaN  NaN  
41         NaN       NaN NaN  NaN         NaN  NaN  ]
```

Comment: can you do `print(df)` before `nametxt = ...`, the problem is clear, just need to know in order to give you the solution. Bottom line, read_html returns a list of dataframes, so you need to do something like `df[0].to_csv`

Comment: See my edit in the post

Comment: What I do not get, I do read_html in a loop right, so it should only read 1 table and return 1 table instead of a list? The df[0] solution seems to work!

Comment: by definition `read_html` returns a list, so even if the list has only one element, you need to call it using list syntax, glad it's working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a similar question with solution [Get HTML table into pandas Dataframe, not list of dataframe objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38486477/get-html-table-into-pandas-dataframe-not-list-of-dataframe-objects)

Essentially, pd.read_html returns a list of dataframes and you need to select one to call to_csv.