# scrape a table in a website with python (no table tag)

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape daily the stock value of a product. This is the web https://funds.ddns.net/f.php?isin=ES0110407097. And this is the code I'm trying:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_string = 'https://funds.ddns.net/f.php?isin=ES0110407097'    
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string, 'lxml') 

new_table = pd.DataFrame(columns=range(0,2), index = [0])  

row_marker = 0


column_marker = 0
 for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
     columns = soup.find_all('td')
     for column in columns:
         new_table.iat[row_marker,column_marker] = column.get_text()
         column_marker += 1

print(new_table)
```

I would like to get in Python the same format I can see in the web, both the data and the number. How can I get it, please?

Comment: Hi, I am not posting a solution, but I have used this method some times before, and It was useful for me to scrap some information from webs. I used BeautifulSoap, you can find a link here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ and here you can find an sample tutorial of usage: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-web-scrape-with-python-in-4-minutes-bc49186a8460 Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a simpler way for that particular page:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://funds.ddns.net/f.php?isin=ES0110407097'    
resp = requests.get(url)

new_table = pd.read_html(resp.text)[0]
print(new_table.head(5))
```

Output:

```
            0          1
0       FECHA     VL:EUR
1  2019-12-20  120170000
2  2019-12-19  119600000
3  2019-12-18  119420000
4  2019-12-17  119390000
```

Comment: You can read the table via `pd.read_html(url)` directly without using requests !

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη - correct, but if you do that, your `new_table` is a list, not a dataframe, so at that point you need to convert `new_table[0]` to dataframe, so I don't think it saves that much time... But, in principle, you are right.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38486477/get-html-table-into-pandas-dataframe-not-list-of-dataframe-objects