# get multiple wiki tables pass to csv

Tags: python

How to get tables and pass to csv file?

```
import pandas as pd 

# 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions'

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions'
tables = pd.read_html(url)

df = tables

df.to_csv("linux_distros.csv", sep=",")
```

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get HTML table into pandas Dataframe, not list of dataframe objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38486477/get-html-table-into-pandas-dataframe-not-list-of-dataframe-objects)

Comment: I din't undestant how it solve my question, if I do this df[0] ###<-- Pandas DataFrame, I'll get one single table, I need get all tables and save into CSV file.
I tried a loop use this idea, but I realy lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read_html returns a list of dataframes, one for each table found.
You'd need to concatenate all relevant tables and then save that to a csv.

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions'
tables = pd.read_html(url)

tables = [table for table in tables if ('Distribution' in table.columns and 'Description' in table.columns)]
# Concatenate all tables
df = pd.concat(tables, ignore_index=True)
# Save to CSV
df.to_csv("linux_distros.csv", sep=",")
```